# Manually Creating "Groups" from the Data and Testing their Statistical Significance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, predictive-models, simulation, multiple-comparisons

I am working on the following problem: Suppose a hospital has a dataset containing the **weight of an individual patient** and the **number of days** that this patient spent in the hospital (i.e. each row contains information on an individual patient). The hospital believes that heavier patients spend on average more time in the hospital. Using the R programming language, I tried to simulate a realistic looking dataset) :

```
set.seed(123)

weight_of_patient <- rnorm(10000, 180,4)
days_spent_in_hospital <- rnorm(10000, 40,8)
data_1 = data.frame(weight_of_patient, days_spent_in_hospital)

weight_of_patient <- rnorm(10000, 190,4)
days_spent_in_hospital <- rnorm(10000, 60 ,7)
data_2 = data.frame(weight_of_patient, days_spent_in_hospital)

weight_of_patient <- rnorm(10000, 200,4)
days_spent_in_hospital <- rnorm(10000, 100 ,10)
data_3 = data.frame(weight_of_patient, days_spent_in_hospital)

weight_of_patient <- rnorm(250, 170,4)
days_spent_in_hospital <- rnorm(250, 100 ,20)
data_4 = data.frame(weight_of_patient, days_spent_in_hospital)

weight_of_patient <- rnorm(500, 205,2)
days_spent_in_hospital <- rnorm(500, 50 ,10)
data_5 = data.frame(weight_of_patient, days_spent_in_hospital)

final_data = rbind(data_1, data_2, data_3, data_4, data_5)

head(final_data)
  weight_of_patient days_spent_in_hospital
1          178.2782               37.21415
2          183.6867               44.68650
3          169.8296               40.55876
4          182.7736               52.42323
5          180.4126               25.75941
6          185.9051               38.18974
```

A plot of the data would look like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(final_data, aes(x=final_data$weight_of_patient, y=final_data$days_spent_in_hospital)) + geom_point() + xlab("Weight (lbs) ") + ylab("Number of Days Spent in Hospital") + ggtitle("Number of Days Spent in Hospital vs. Weight of Patient")
```

[image]

**Problem:** The hospital is interested in creating 3 ("logical") groups of patients based on their weight and how long they spend in the hospital. These groups will be used for planning purposes, communicating with the patient's family, etc. These groups must be easily explainable to the patient's family (i.e. no random forest, no neural network, no gradient boosting, no regression models, etc.). When the analysis is finished, the groups should look something like this:

- **Group 1**:  Weight < 180 Lbs: AT LEAST 80% of the patients in Group 1 spend less than 50 days in the hospital
- **Group 2**:  Weight >180 and < 200 lbs: AT LEAST 80% of the patients in Group 2 spend less than 100 days in the hospital
- **Group 3**:  Weight > 200 lbs: AT LEAST 80% of the patients in Group 3 spend less than 120 days in the hospital

On some level, this problem is easier than the common types of supervised classification problems. If patient in the weight class from Group 2 spends less than 50 days in the hospital (the time designated for patients in Group 1) - this is not considered as a "problem". But if a patient from the weight class from Group 1 spends more than 100 days in the hospital (the time designated for patients in "higher weight groups") - this is considered a problem. That is, it's always better to overestimate the time someone will spend in the hospital instead of underestimating. I tried to draw this cost-misclassification table below (for some arbitrary group criteria):

[image]

The most natural way that this kind of problem is solved is by using "clustering algorithms" (e.g. K-Means Clustering):

```
kmeans_clustering <- kmeans(final_data,3)
final_data$cluster = kmeans_clustering$cluster

ggplot(final_data, aes(x=final_data$weight_of_patient, y=final_data$days_spent_in_hospital)) + geom_point(aes(color = factor(kmeans_clustering$cluster) )) + xlab("Weight (lbs) ") + ylab("Number of Days Spent in Hospital")   + 
    labs(color = "Cluster Membership")+  ggtitle("Number of Days Spent in Hospital vs. Weight of Patient")
```

However, the "clustering boundaries" will inevitably be "too irregular" and difficult to explain:

[image]

Instead, it seems like the following approach would be more suitable for this kind of problem (e.g. pick some arbitrary weight groups (red) and their corresponding 80% percentiles (blue) - note: general drawing):

[image]

**My Question:** I would be interested in testing how "statistically reliable" a given set of groups is likely to represent future data. E.g. In the future, can we expect AT LEAST 80% of people who weigh between 180 lbs and 200 lbs to spend less than 100 days in the hospital?

To do this, I first arbitrarily chose weight groups (using the same definitions as above) and their corresponding hospital times.  I then created a "cross validation" style procedure that takes random subsets of the data (e.g. 70%) and checks how many of the patients within each weight group match their corresponding hospital stay time (taking into account the cost-misclassification). I repeat this process 1000 times:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

results <- list()
for (i in 1:1000) {
  train_i<-sample_frac(final_data, 0.7)
 
 
  
  train_i$weight_group = as.factor(ifelse(train_i$weight_of_patient < 180 , "A", ifelse(train_i$weight_of_patient  > 180  & train_i$weight_of_patient  < 200, "B", "C")))
  
 train_i$predicted_days = ifelse(train_i$weight_group == "A", 50, ifelse( train_i$weight_group == "B", 100,120))
  
train_i$accuracy = ifelse(train_i$days_spent_in_hospital < train_i$predicted_days, 1,0)
  
  results_tmp = data.frame(train_i %>%
                           group_by(weight_group) %>%
                           dplyr::summarize(Mean = mean(accuracy, na.rm=TRUE)))
  
  results_tmp$iteration = i
  
  results_tmp$total_mean = mean(train_i$accuracy)
  results[[i]] <- results_tmp
}
results
results_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)

final_table = dcast(setDT(results_df), iteration_number ~ weight_group, value.var = 'mean')
```

Here are the results (each row is an iteration, each column represents the accuracy of each patient group for that iteration):

```
head(final_table)

 iteration         A         B         C
1:         1 0.8367238 0.8740661 0.9738951
2:         2 0.8325719 0.8721123 0.9728831
3:         3 0.8299191 0.8740135 0.9747227
4:         4 0.8354497 0.8728378 0.9768330
5:         5 0.8297247 0.8756551 0.9750973
6:         6 0.8359587 0.8734632 0.9768683
```

The above table be used to check on average, how many patients from each weight group spent less than their designated time in the hospital (in the simulation):

```
 mean(final_table$A)
[1] 0.8329073

 mean(final_table$B)
[1] 0.8740477

mean(final_table$C)
[1] 0.9748849
```

We can also look at the histograms of these weight groups (A = 1, B = 2, C = 3) throughout the simulation (useful for confidence intervals):

```
 par(mfrow=c(1,3))

     hist(final_table$A, breaks = 90, main = "Distribution of Patients in Weight Group 1 Who Spent Less than 50 Days")


     hist(final_table$B, breaks = 90,  main = "Distribution of Patients in Weight Group 2 Who Spent Less than 100 Days")

     hist(final_table$C, breaks = 90,  main = "Distribution of Patients in Weight Group 3 Who Spent Less than 120 Days")
```

[image]

**Conclusion:** Is the statistical methodology that I used in this question reasonable? After performing this simulation, can we reasonably expect that (provided our data is well representative of how future data will behave):

- **Group 1**:  Weight < 180 Lbs: AT LEAST 80% of the patients in Group 1 spend less than 50 days in the hospital (in the simulation, we saw that on average 83% of patients in Group 1 spent less than their designated time in the hospital)
- **Group 2**:  Weight >180 and < 200 lbs: AT LEAST 80% of the patients in Group 2 spend less than 100 days in the hospital (in the simulation, we saw that on average 87% of patients in Group 2 spent less than their designated time in the hospital)
- **Group 3**:  Weight > 200 lbs: AT LEAST 80% of the patients in Group 3 spend less than 120 days in the hospital (in the simulation, we saw that on average 97% of patients in Group 3 spent less than their designated time in the hospital)

Through simulation, I tried to test how well the "weight and time groups" generalize to unseen samples of data, even to samples which are unfavorable to initial hypothesis (i.e. outliers: heavier patients that spend shorter amounts of time at the hospital and lighter patients that spend longer amounts of time at the hospital).

I know this is a unusual problem which has a strange criteria for accuracy/misclassification, where common statistical methods can not be used, and a seemingly arbitrary target is in place (i.e. 80% of patients in each weight group spending less than their designated time in the hospital). I know that these weight/time groups also seem arbitrary (e.g. these weight/time groups could represent established industry standards that an individual hospital wants to see how well they follow) - but from a statistics point of view, is the methodology logical?

Thanks

Comment: Because this is not a designed study. conclusions must be restricted to this particular hospital for the particular time period spanned by the dataset. Other hospitals may serve different socioeconomic classes, through its reputation draw patients with the most severe diagnoses, etc.

Comment: @ BruceET: thank you so much for your reply! I agree with you - conclusions must be restricted to this specific hospital. But in this case, do you think that the statistical methodology proposed in this question would allow for "reasonable statistical conclusions" to be made on this particular hospital? Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe only for a brief window of time. Over the last 18 months being overweight has been especially problematic for Covid patients.

Comment: @ BruceET: thank you so much for your reply! I agree with your comments, the last 18 months being overweight has been especially problematic for Covid patients. But suppose we had some way of ascertaining that the current data is similar to the data used in the analysis. In this case, does the statistical methodology proposed in this question make sense? Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: In your k-means analysis, is it showing clusters for short, medium and long stays in hospital?  Am I wrong to be looking for clusters for lightweight, intermediate, and heavy patients?

Comment: @TMBailey: thank you for your reply! If you look at the first plot of the data, there appears to be a general linear trend that shows a linear correlation between increasing weight and increasing time spent in the hospital. The k means clustering algorithm naturally picked up on this.

Comment: I guess an alternative to bootstrap simulations might be to look at conditional distributions and [compound distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution).  Your thresholds set a conditional probability of 80% that length of stay is less than the threshold given the weight group.  If you choose a patient at random the weight group is a random variable.  I think in principle the outcome of the simulations could perhaps be calculated in closed form.

Comment: @ TMBailey: thank you for your reply! I will look into it more! In the mean time, do you have any comments about the approach I took for this problem? Does it make sense to you? Thanks!

Comment: The approach described in the question looks vaguely plausible to me, *but* I haven't done a lot of bootstrapping.  A pragmatic approach would be to (a) be transparent about the methodology so people are in a position to suggest improvements and (b) monitor results.  Be aware that people cannot reason well about proportions and maybe emphasise "most patients..." rather than "80% of patients...".  Finally, it makes sense to use weight on its own only if it is the strongest predictor of length of stay.  Else one or more other independent variables would be better.